# $2$ digit numbers that are divisible by 5

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility

I am trying to find all $2$ digit numbers that are divisible by $5$. So, if we put the $0$ at the last position - _$0$, we have $V_9^1=9$ options for the first digit. If we put $5$ at the last position - _$5$,  we have $V_9^1=9$, but this includes $05$. The total number is: $2V_9^1-1=17.$ Aren't they $18$?

Comment: If you put the $5$ second, the $9$ options for the first digit don't include $0$.

Comment: They do include $0$. Why not?

Comment: If you are including $0$ to $V_9^1$, then there are $10$ options for each case and the cases to be excluded should be $00$ and $05$. Otherwise, you don't have to exclude $05$ in the first place.

Comment: for $5$ at last digit , there would be $1,2,3,....,9$ total of 9 options.

Comment: @saulspatz, when I put $5$ at the last position, we have the numbers $\{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,0\}$.

Comment: @Stellar Why aren't you counting $5$ as an option?  Isn't $55$ divisible by $5$?

Comment: @saulspatz, yeah, I got it. I shouldn't use combinatorics.

Comment: I think perhaps you need to explain your logic thoroughly. What is $V_9^1$ and why are you using it? You seem to think you are using it rather than $10$ because you can't have a two digit number where both digits are the same? So for $0$ you are only allowed $1...9$ and for $5$ you are allowed $0,1...4,6,..9$? Why are you assuming that? We, reading your question, all assumed you were using it be to have a two digit number the first digit can't be $0$ and you have $1.....9$ options for both the $0$ and $5$ as final digit. .... which is the correct way to think of it.

Comment: " I shouldn't use combinatorics."  Well, you can. But you have to use it in a way that reflects the question. You aren't choosing two digits without repetition (is that what $V_a^b$ means? $\frac {a!}{b!}$?)  You are choosing with repetition so *not* $V_9^1$ but $9^1$.  (To choose $b$ from $a$ without repetition, order matters, you use $V_a^b=\frac {a!}{b!}$.  To choose $b$ from $a$ with possible repetition, order matters, you use $a^b$.)  As Mr. Natural says "Always use the right tool for the job."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $9$ cases where the last digit ends with $5$ and $05$ is not one of them. Hence answer is $9+9=18$.

You can also divide the largest two-digit number $(95)$ by $5$ and subtract the number of one-digit multiples.

$={95\over 5}-{5\over 5} =19-1=18$

Comment: Thank you. Why the second solution works? What's the logic?

Comment: It simple inclusion-exclusion principle. Think about it for a minute, you will surely get it.

Answer (score 1):

Two digits multiples of $5$ are $$10,15,20,....,95$$ That is $5$ times the elements of $${2,3,4,..,19}$$

Thus there are $18$ of them.